# Measure page load time

Tags: performance, testing

Is there a free **IE addon**, that analyses the page load of websites?

I look for the following meaures:

- Download time for each page element (images, etc)
- Problems/errors for each page element (such as access denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Dynatrace for IE http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/ and you can perform more in-depth analysis using dynatrace

Answer (score 2):

Try [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar).